# How do I find where ElasticSearch is installing my plugins?

Tags: directory, elasticsearch

I have installed elasticsearch with `brew install elasticsearch`. My plugins seem to reside in `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.8/plugins`. With `cat $( which plugin )` I see a `ES_HOME` variable that contains the correct path.

**Is there a way to ask elastic for `ES_HOME` or the plugins directory?**

---

#### EDIT

What I am looking for is the directory used by the **plugin** executable to install the plugins when I do `plugin -install something`. I want to use that path in a script to fire up elastic search.

Comment: Being an old question, be mindful that instillation using Elasticsearch plugin has been deprecated since ES 5. In other words, all new/X-Pack features come bundled from version 5.0 onward.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

To find your elasticsearch *home directory* & *install plugin(s)* follow these steps below.

**Locate your home directory**    *( Look for Settings -> Path -> Home for value )*

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/_nodes/settings?pretty=true"
```

**Goto Location** *(Example settings.path.home value: /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.5.0)*

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.5.0
```

**Install Plugin**  *(Example plugin: [mobz/elasticsearch-head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/))*

```
$ bin/plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

Comment: This is an oooold question. Thanks for the complete answer though.

Comment: just to leave it here, this helps for me using the APT method installing [elastic search via repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/setup-repositories.html)

`sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head`

Comment: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677563/connection-refused-error-on-elastic-search

Answer (score 33):

I  used this command:

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty=true&settings=true"
```

Check next setting: nodes - settings - path - plugins and use it as your plugins directory.

Comment: `curl "localhost:9200/_nodes?pretty=true&settings=true"`

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem as you and I was able to locate the ES_HOME directory by following 
@imotiv's suggestion.

Simply call `PATH_TO_SERVER:9200/_cluster/nodes?settings=true&pretty=true`

Therein you'll see the `path.home` entry. That is your ES working directory.

Once you locate your ElasticSearch home folder, in my case `/usr/share/elasticsearch`, `cd` down to that location.

Once there, you could simply run `bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic/1.3.0` and it will automatically do the rest for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but hopefully this will help. There are a couple of way to find the plugins directory for elasticsearch. You can set `plugins: TRACE` in the `logging.yml` file, it will cause elasticsearch to log the full path of plugins that it's loading. You can also execute

```
$ curl "localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes?settings=true&pretty=true"
```

to check the current settings. Elasticsearch is using location specified in the `path.plugins` settings to load plugins. If `path.plugins` is not set, it will use `plugins` directory in the directory specified by the `path.home` setting.

Comment: I am sorry but upon reading my question again it seems I missed a critical point: I am looking for the directory that the **plugin** executable is using by default to install the plugins when I do `plugin -install something`. I want to use that path in a script to fire up elastic search.

Comment: This is non-trivial. If you want to do it in a clean way, you will need to load several config files and check several environment settings. I think the simplest way would be to write a small java app that would load settings and then get pluginsFile from `org.elasticsearch.env.Environment`. Basically it would be the first 2 lines of the main method of `org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager` except instead of checking that path exists, it would return it to the caller.