# How to specify a default-mapping.json in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to add a default-mapping.json file but I'm not sure if it is read. How can I properly test it? And if it is failing to be read, how do I specify Elasticsearch to read that file?
This is the file in /etc/default:

```
# Run Elasticsearch as this user ID and group ID
#ES_USER=elasticsearch
#ES_GROUP=elasticsearch

# Heap Size (defaults to 256m min, 1g max)
#ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g

# Heap new generation
#ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE=

# max direct memory
#ES_DIRECT_SIZE=

# Maximum number of open files, defaults to 65535.
#MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535

# Maximum locked memory size. Set to "unlimited" if you use the
# bootstrap.mlockall option in elasticsearch.yml. You must also set
# ES_HEAP_SIZE.
#MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited

# Maximum number of VMA (Virtual Memory Areas) a process can own
#MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144

# Elasticsearch log directory
#LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch data directory
#DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch work directory
#WORK_DIR=/tmp/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
#CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration file (elasticsearch.yml)
#CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

# Additional Java OPTS
#ES_JAVA_OPTS=

# Configure restart on package upgrade (true, every other setting will lead to not restarting)
#RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true
```

And then this is the default-mapping.json placed in the /etc/elasticsearch

```
{
    "_default_": {
        "_all": { "enabled": false },
        "_source": { "compress": true },
         "properties" : {
            "message" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed" },
            "source_host" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "tags": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "type" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why would you add fields in the default mapping file?

Comment: When I query the fields in Kibana, I don't want it to be tokenized by whitespace and not lowercased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good way to create a default mapping in elasticsearch is via *templates*, here is what yours would look like:

```
{
    "template_11": {
        "template": "*",
        "mappings": {
            "_default_": {
                "_all": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "_source": {
                    "compress": true
                },
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "analyzed"
                    },
                    "source_host": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Put this template inside `$config_dir/templates/template_11.json`

If you're unsure what is your path, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/23338461/1619406

For example, mine was `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/templates/templates_11.json`

Now, every time you create a new index, it will use this template as the default mapping.

Hope this helps,

References:

[Index Template](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html)

[Default Mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html)

---

**Update**: the aforementioned answer is no longer applicable for versions 2.x or 5.x according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021339/how-to-load-a-index-template-file-into-elasticsearch-when-it-starts-up), which references these two links in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/packetbeat-template.html), and [discussion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_index_api_changes.html#_file_based_index_templates).

Comment: I'm trying to make the fields in Kibana not be tokenizing on whitespace, but it seems to not be working. How should I properly test what the problem is?

Comment: You can also use the api to put your templates. Check here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

Test the analyzer used on the indexing the field value using the /analyze endpoint.

curl -s -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/url-test/_analyze?text=http://example.com&pretty'

You need to define a raw field(not analyzed) to search

```
"fieldname": {
          "type": "string",
          "norms": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "fielddata": {
            "format": "disabled"
          },
          "fields": {
             "raw" : {"type": "string",
                      "index" : "not_analyzed",
                      "doc_values" : true,
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                     }
               }
        },
```