# How to load a index template file into elasticsearch when it starts up?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

In elasticsearch v1.5, Index templates can be placed within the config location (path.conf) under the templates directory `elasticsearch/config/templates`. However, I found this template will not be loaded after I upgrade to v2.3 or v5.3. Is any way to load index template?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/indices-templates.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No other way in 2.x or 5.x. This has been removed starting with 2.0.0-beta1 version of Elasticsearch.

This was documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_index_api_changes.html#_file_based_index_templates).

And reasons and discussions around this can be found [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10870).